# How to extract most related item from a table?

Tags: mysql, excel, data-analysis

I have a project for retail store, to get most related products that has been sold with certain product.

for example, this is table of invoices

---

```
Invoice1, Panadol, Brufen, Celebrex
Invoice2, Panadol, Brufen, Comitrex
Invoice3, Panadol, Congestal
```

---

In this table, the most related item to Panadol is Brufen.

I am asking for forumla in Excel or Mysql to extract this information automatically.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  -  although it looks as though your schema design needs some work

Comment: I hope your invoice has 1 row per item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data looks like this

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t 
(id int, item varchar(20));
insert into t values
(1,'paracetemol'),
(1,'brufen'),
(1,'cele'),
(2,'brufen'),
(2,'paracetemol'),
(2,'comi'),
(3,'con'),
(4,'paracetemol'),
(4,'cele');
```

Then

```
select item, count(*) obs
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.item = 'paracetemol')
and item <> 'paracetemol'
group by item 
order by count(*) desc limit 1;
```

Where the existence check only looks for invoices where paracetemol is part.

```
+--------+-----+
| item   | obs |
+--------+-----+
| brufen |   2 |
+--------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This code does not deal with ties (but you didn't specify that it should)

Comment: That is very good. But It returns the most repeated item in all table if it cannot find a related one. How to avoid that?

Comment: I am not clear what you mean can you expand please.Possibly by expanding my model and posting to sqlfiddle

Comment: I am sorry I was little confused with my table, But now it works fine with your code :) Thank you very much!